# How to reuse a result column in an expression for another result column

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

Example:

```
SELECT
   (SELECT SUM(...) FROM ...) as turnover,
   (SELECT SUM(...) FROM ...) as cost,
   turnover - cost as profit
```

Sure this is invalid (at least in Postgres) but how to achieve the same in a query without rewriting the sub-query twice?

Comment: Depends on details, such as columns & tables involved.

Comment: @OMG Ponis: Like? Isn't there a general way for such?

Comment: I agree with @OMG. That said, if you can write *one* subquery that returns both `turnover` and `cost` as columns, the query wrapped around that subquery can perform `turnover - cost`. For more details, we'll need some details about your schema.

Comment: Also consider using "common table expressions" aka CTE. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686919/is-possible-to-reuse-subqueries and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html

Comment: Edited title: this question doesn't focus on reusing subqueries (tables) but rather single columns, unlike http://stackoverflow.com/q/2686919/648265 .

Comment: See also this answer in [how to use alias in calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18020948/2641825) `SELECT 10 AS my_num, 
       (SELECT my_num) * 5 AS another_number
FROM table`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Like so:

```
SELECT
   turnover,
   cost,
   turnover - cost as profit
from (
   (SELECT SUM(...) FROM ...) as turnover,
   (SELECT SUM(...) FROM ...) as cost
   ) as partial_sums
```

Comment: Usually when you do `select from table1, table2` you get the CROSS JOIN of the two tables. What does `select from (table1, table2) as bla` (as you have here) do with the two tables?

Comment: @CharlBotha: it's not select from (foo, bar). It's [select] (select sum from foo), (select sum from bar) [from nothing].

Comment: In your example above, you have `... from ((select ...) as turnover, (select ...) as cost) as partial_sums` -- I'm still wondering how exactly the turnover and cost sub-selects are combined?

Comment: @CharlBotha: they're two scalars, in very much the same way as you'd go `select 1 as foo, 2 as bar`.

Comment: Thank you very much! (I did not see that they were scalars, probably because I was struggling with an own example of a correlated subquery from which I was trying to aggregate multiple columns in different ways)

Comment: What about if the subselect uses a common FROM as well :S

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Postgres 10, I'm getting a syntax error on line 6 on the comma after turnover.

Comment: @kralyk: You sure you didn't forget parenthesis? Also note that Alex offers an equivalent query that one might consider cleaner.

Comment: This syntax is invalid. You cannot alias a table list in SQL, only join tables and other table expressions can be aliased. Even if you could, it wouldn't be necessary. Just write `FROM (SELECT ..) t1, (SELECT ..) t2`

Answer (score 15):

You could reuse the query like this:

```
WITH 
  TURNOVER AS (
    SELECT SUM(...) FROM ...)
  ),
  COST AS(
    SELECT SUM(...) FROM ...
  )

SELECT *
FROM(
 SELECT
   TURNOVER.sum as SUM_TURNOVER
 FROM
 TURNOVER,COST
 WHERE ....
) AS a
```

This is equivalent to :

```
SELECT *
FROM(
 SELECT
   TURNOVER.sum as SUM_TURNOVER
 FROM
 (
   SELECT SUM(...) FROM ...)
 )AS TURNOVER,
 (
   SELECT SUM(...) FROM ...
 )AS COST
 WHERE ....
) AS a
```

There is a point to note here. The first method is more readable and reusable, but the second method might be faster, because the DB might choose a better plan for it.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps the sql "with" clause could help, as presented here http://orafaq.com/node/1879 (other databases such as Postgres do it as well, not just oracle).

Comment: This feature is called "common table expressions" aka CTE. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686919/is-possible-to-reuse-subqueries

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT turnover, cost, turnover - cost
FROM
(
SELECT
(SELECT ...) as turnover,
(SELECT ...) as cost
) as Temp
```

Comment: if turnover and cost are table aliases, you definitely can't do this: turnover - cost as profit

Comment: Invalid:
ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias
HINT:  For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.

Comment: In my query Temp is the alias for the subquery in FROM

Answer (score 4):

Actually I did a lot of work on this, and hit many brick walls, but finally figured out an answer - more of a hack - but it worked very well and reduced the read overhead of my queries by 90%....

So rather than duplicating the correlated query many times to retrieve multiple columns from the subquery, I just used concat all the values I want to return into a comma separated varchar, and then unroll them again in the application...

So instead of

```
select a,b,
(select x from bigcorrelatedsubquery) as x,
(select y from bigcorrelatedsubquery) as y,
(select z from bigcorrelatedsubquery) as z
from outertable
```

I now do

```
select a,b,
(select convert(varchar,x)+','+convert(varchar,x)+','+convert(varchar,x)+',' 
from bigcorrelatedsubquery) from bigcorrelatedquery) as xyz
from outertable
group by country
```

I now have all three correlated 'scalar' values I needed but only had to execute the correlated subquery once instead of three times.

Comment: What you _should_ have done is `JOIN` the `bigcorrelatedsubquery` with `outertable` once, instead of repeating it multiple times or resorting to the concat hack. Even in the worst case you could have factored that subquery as a CTE to avoid repeating it.

Answer (score 3):

I think the following will work:

```
SELECT turnover, cost, turnover-cost as profit FROM
   (SELECT 1 AS FAKE_KEY, SUM(a_field) AS TURNOVER FROM some_table) a
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT 1 AS FAKE_KEY, SUM(a_nother_field) AS COST FROM some_other_table) b
USING (FAKE_KEY);
```

Not tested on animals - you'll be first!  :-)

Share and enjoy.

Comment: You don't need `INNER JOIN` with a fake key. Just use a `CROSS JOIN`, or list the derived tables in a table list: `FROM (SELECT ..), (SELECT ..)`

Answer (score 0):

Use a cross apply or outer apply.

```
SELECT
  Calc1.turnover,
  Calc2.cost,
  Calc3.profit
from
   cross apply ((SELECT SUM(...) as turnover FROM ...)) as Calc1
   cross apply ((SELECT SUM(...) as cost FROM ...)) as Calc2

   /*
     Note there is no from Clause in Calc 3 below.
     This is how you can "stack" formulas like in excel.
     You can return any number of columns, not just one.
   */
   cross apply (select Calc1.turnover - Calc2.cost as profit) as Calc3
```

Comment: That's T-SQL syntax, only supported by SQL Server and Oracle. In PostgreSQL, this approach would require standard SQL `LATERAL` derived tables.

Answer (score 0):

this is pretty old but i ran into this problem and saw this post but didnt manage to solve my problem using the given answers so i eventually arrived at this solution :

if your query is :

```
SELECT
   (SELECT SUM(...) FROM ...) as turnover,
   (SELECT SUM(...) FROM ...) as cost,
   turnover - cost as profit
```

you can turn it into a subquery and then use the fields such as :

```
SELECT *,(myFields.turnover-myFields.cost) as profit 
FROM
(      
SELECT
       (SELECT SUM(...) FROM ...) as turnover,
       (SELECT SUM(...) FROM ...) as cost

) as myFields
```

i'm not entirely sure if this is a bad way of doing things but performance wise it seems okay for me querying over `224,000` records took 1.5 sec
not sure if its later on turned into 2x of the same sub query by DB.

Answer (score -1):

You can use user defined variables like this

```
SELECT
   @turnover := (SELECT SUM(...) FROM ...),
   @cost := (SELECT SUM(...) FROM ...),
   @turnover - @cost as profit
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html

Comment: Perhaps this helps in MySQL but for Postgres?