# How to reuse a sub query in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I have query like the following

```
select columns
from (select columns1
      from result_set
      where condition_common and condition1) as subset1
      join
      (select columns2
       from result_set
       where condition_common and condition2) as subset2 
      on subset1.somekey = subset2.somekey
```

I want to somehow reuse

```
select columns
from result_set
where condition_common
```

I have oversimplified the above query, but the above select in reality is huge and complicated. I dont want to have the burden of making sure both are in sync

I dont have any means of programmatically reusing it. T-SQL is ruled out. I can only write simple queries. This is an app limitation.

Is there a way to reuse same subquery, in a single statement

Comment: By PLSQL i only meant the ability to use variables, procedures etc. Whats the correct lingo for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is possible to reuse subqueries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686919/is-possible-to-reuse-subqueries)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use a [Common Table Expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (CTE) if you're using SQL Server 2005+:

```
with cte as (
      select columns
      from result_set
      where condition_common
    )
select columns
from cte  as subset1
      join
      cte as subset2 
         on subset1.somekey = subset2.somekey
where otherconditions
```