# How to reuse query of IN sub query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below query

```
select a.id, a.user_id, a.approver_id, a.second_approver_id 
from tbl_approve_master a 
WHERE user_id in (select id from tbl_user where name like '%john%')
or approver_id in (select id from tbl_user where name like '%john%') 
or second_approver_id in (select id from tbl_user where name like '%john%')
```

How could I reuse the query statement of `in` ? I tried the accept answer of [How to reuse a sub query in sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987317/how-to-reuse-a-sub-query-in-sql) as

```
with cte as (select id from tbl_user where name like '%john%')
select a.id, a.user_id, a.approver_id, a.second_approver_id 
from tbl_approve_master a 
WHERE user_id in cte
or approver_id in cte 
or second_approver_id in cte
```

but this does not ok. How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select a.id, a.user_id, a.approver_id, a.second_approver_id 
from tbl_approve_master a 
WHERE exists (
    select * 
    from tbl_user u
    where u.name like '%john%'
    and u.id in (a.user_id, a.approver_id, a.second_approver_id)
)
```

Comment: Thank you sir. That is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
select a.id, a.user_id, a.approver_id, a.second_approver_id 
from tbl_approve_master a
where exists (select 1 from tbl_user at
              where (a.user_id  = at.id
                or a.approver_id  = at.id
                or a.second_approver_id =id)
                and (at.name like '%john%'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
;with cte as (select id from tbl_user where name like '%john%')
select a.id, a.user_id, a.approver_id, a.second_approver_id 
from tbl_approve_master a 
join cte 
    on user_id = cte.id or approver_id = cte.id or second_approver_id = cte.id
```

Comment: I got duplicate results.